# .NET Core 3.1 File Result is Slow

Tags: c#, file, web, .net-core

I've a .NET Core 3.1 API running inside a Linux docker container on an B2S Azure VM.

My API is configured to add ResponseCompression

```
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
            });

            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
            });
```

I have a simple service that get some bytes from memory cache and return that as a file to my client.

```
[HttpGet("product/image/{id}"), Route("product/image")]
        public virtual IActionResult ProductImage([FromQuery] string id)
        {
            try
            {
                Service.GetProductImage(id, out byte[] content, out string contentType);
                return File(content, contentType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return CatchException(ex);
            }
        }
```

If I create a Diagnostics.StopWatch to measure the delay of my "GetProductImage" method, it took 0ms to run.

The problem is, when I open the browser and try a GET on any image, it tooks about 1s to get the image. If I open 12 images at the same time, it took about 2s per image. Every log of my ellapsed ms from the GetProductImage shows 0ms of ellapsed time.
Every image has about 500kb.

Any idea on how could I increase that performance ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that adding ResponseCompression slows the GET?

Comment: Does `Service.GetProductImage` only materialise the result when the result is used - in the same fashion as a LINQ query? It may not make a difference, but have you checked if it goes faster without the ResponseCompression? Do you see the same problem when running it locally (e.g. on the dev machine)?

Comment: What happens if you remove compression altogether?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't that your connection to Azure / your website is slow (rather than it being a server side issue)?

Comment: Some feedback after a loot of tests.

The images were not being compressed, I had to explicitly add their proper mime-types so that they were. I made a routine to create thumbnails with 60% of the original size of the image, which reduced its size by more than 50%.
I changed the default Azure disk size to have a higher data rate / sec.
After that, responses fell by approx 2s to 300-400ms.